# Skybound Gecko. How can I click item by class name?

Tags: c#, gecko, geckofx

This item look like this:

```
//First "button"
<td ref="somethink_ref1" class="class_name">
        <b>Text_1</b><br>
        text<span class="class_name_1">text</span><br>
        <span class="class_name_2">text</span><br>
        <span class="class_name_3">text</span>text
</td>
//Second "button"
<td ref="somethink_ref2" class="class_name">
        <b>Text_1</b><br>
        text<span class="class_name_1">text</span><br>
        <span class="class_name_2">text</span><br>
        <span class="class_name_3">text</span>text
</td>
```

There isn't any id's and when i'm using this:

```
        GeckoElementCollection tagsCollection = geckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("td");

        foreach (GeckoElement currentTag in tagsCollection)
        {
            if (currentTag.GetAttribute("class").Equals("class_name"))
            {
                 //currentTag.CLICK THIS!;
            }
            //delay some seconds to click next button...
        }
```

I have no idea to replace 'currentTag.CLICK THIS' to real click call...

Answer (score 3):

If you using a relative new version of [geckofx](https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-29.0/downloads) then you can do something like this:

```
foreach (GeckoElement currentTag in tagsCollection)
        {
            if (currentTag.GetAttribute("class").Equals("class_name"))
            {
                 ((GeckoHtmlElement)currentTag).Click()
            }
            //delay some seconds to click next button...
        }
```

Although I would probably would do something like this:

```
var elements = geckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByClassName("class_name").Where(x is GeckoHtmlElement)
```

to locate the nodes.